# custom model moved to scikit-learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

In short: I wrote a custom model which worked well, but tried to re-implement it in scikit-learn, and that is working poorly. **I am not sure if my code (below) is buggy, if I'm missing recommended preprocessing for a scikit-learn project, or if my choice of model is wrong.**

The goal of the project is: Given the title of a blog post about a product, predict the actual product that is being written about. There are about 2,000 products overall.

First I built a custom model, using some "language model" principles that I adopted from a textbook.

I went through the labeled data and for each product, got a tally of all words used in all its titles (e.g. car:10,windshield:3,husband:2,tires:5}). Then to make new predictions for unseen titles, I tokenized the title and constructed a score for each product: score=(word1's percent frequency in the product's tally) * (word2's percent frequency in the product's tally) etc. I had a default low percent frequency for words that were missing for the product (rather than using 0 which would mess up the rankings).

Then I'd sort the products by score and return the top 5. I found that 87% of the time that I did this, the correct product was within those top 5.

So now I tried implementing it using Naive Bayes in scikit-learn. For now as an evaluation metric I'm using the default score() method which is harsher since the top (only) prediction of the model has to be correct. But I am getting 44% accuracy, which surprises me.

- Notably, I also get 44% when scoring on my training data; I think this should be much higher as the model has already seen this data.
- I also get low scores using Linear Regression: 88% when scoring on the already-seen training data, but 47% for unseen test data.

My code:

```
titles = []
products = []
with open('1pct_singlelabel.csv', 'r', encoding="utf8") as one_pct:
    reader = csv.reader(one_pct, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', lineterminator='\n')
    for i, row in enumerate(reader):
        if (i == 0):
            continue  # skip header
        titles.append(row[2])
        products.append(row[1])

text_train, text_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(titles, products, random_state=0)

vect = CountVectorizer(min_df=0)
vect.fit(titles)
X_train = vect.transform(text_train)
X_test = vect.transform(text_test)

le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
le.fit(products)
y_train = le.transform(y_train)
y_test = le.transform(y_test)

clf = LogisticRegression()
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
print("Logistic Regression: ")
print(clf.score(X_train, y_train))
print(clf.score(X_test, y_test))
```

In sum, I don't understand why scikit-learn is so much worse than my custom code, which was not complex and was (I am told) similar to Naive Bayes. I am not sure if I am using scikit-learn correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are misinterpreting the value of score for [`MultinomialNB`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB.html#sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB). Sklearn does not provide a built-in method for assessing top-k accuracy. The result you see for score is the percentage of samples that the model predicted **exactly**. I imagine that if you were to calculate the top-5 from your naive bayes model in sklearn it would be quite similar to your custom model.

You can use the `predict_proba` method to get the probability assigned to each class. From there you can sort the output and grab the top-k values and check if the actual output is in that output.

```
predictions = clf.predict_proba(test)
k = 5
top_k = np.argsort(probs, axis=1)[-k:]
top_k_preds = clf.classes_[top_k]
```

From there you can check if your actual class is in the top 5 predictions.

Comment: Thanks, I was leaning in that direction so it is good to see you agree. I'm currently working on what you suggest.